# Linq query that returns all records if the search item is null or empty

Tags: c#, linq

I'm not very well versed in linq and I'm trying to eliminate the need to duplicate a bunch of linq queries in my code. I'm hoping that I can modify this linq query to return a full page of results if the value of the string `description` is null or empty. Currently it returns no results in that scenario.

So basically I want this query...

```
return _entities.Schedules.Where(s => s.Description.ToLower().Contains(description.ToLower())))
                        .OrderByWithDirection(x => x.Description, dir)
                        .Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
                        .Take(pageSize)
                        .ToList();
```

...to also return the results that this query would if `description` were null or empty.

```
return _entities.Schedules.OrderByWithDirection(x => x.Description, dir)
                            .Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
                            .Take(pageSize)
                            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LINQ is composable, so you can very simply do this:

```
IQueryable<Schedule> results = _entities.Schedules;

// Only filter on description if a search term has been given
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(description)) {
    results = results.Where(s => 
                  s.Description.ToLower().Contains(description.ToLower())))
}

return results.OrderByWithDirection(x => x.Description, dir)
              .Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
              .Take(pageSize)
              .ToList();
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing now but with all of the different filtering and sorting I'll be doing the code will be a mess of nested if and switch statements which I'm trying to avoid if possible.

Comment: @Splendor: If it ends up being a mess that only means the code needs refactoring. For example, you could pull that `if` out into a method and write `results.FilterByDescription(description).OrderBy...`. And if you *need* complex decision logic to satisfy your requirements, I don't see how cramming all of it into a single statement will make the code any easier to read.

Comment: I misread your answer initially. You blew my mind with this. Thanks!